# Why does this C# code fail to add a row to my database?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Here is my code for adding data to my database.

```
try
{
    String id = txtId.Text;
    String name = txtName.Text;
    String tel = txtTel.Text;
    String add = txtAdd.Text;

    String SqlQuery = @"INSERT INTO [Table]
                        VALUES(@id, @name, @tell, @add)";

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    using (SqlCommand cmnd = new SqlCommand(SqlQuery, con))
    {
        con.Open();

        cmnd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = id;
        cmnd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = name;
        cmnd.Parameters.Add("@tel", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tel;
        cmnd.Parameters.Add("@add", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = add;

        cmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("Saved Sucessfully", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error occurred while saving", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

When I run this code, there is an error message

> Must declare scalar variable @tell

Why do I get an error message like this? Is my code wrong? Can you please help me to get rid of this problem?

This is the error message which I get:

[Error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBQlR.png)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to change the 3rd parameter.

Change `cmnd.Parameters.Add("@tel", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tel;`

To

```
cmnd.Parameters.Add("@tell", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tel;
```

The parameter name is different in your declared sql

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo it seems, it should be `@tell` (notice double `l`).